# Where to put the method. Service layer ( BL ) over repository?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, architecture, repository-pattern, service-layer

I'm confused about one thing. I've used a repository pattern (not generic) in my previous mvc apps and I used to include some kind of business logic there. At this moment I read about service layer pattern where should be included BL. But now I don't know if there is more abstraction and extra code instead of cleary/readable and efficient code.

I want to implement a method like this

```
public void ChangeActiveField(bool isActive, int id)
{
  var objectToUpdate = _context.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.id==id);
  objectToUpdate.IsActive - isActive;
  _context.Entry(objectToUpdate).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
  _context.Save();
}
```

In this code there is a bit of business logic where I change state of one field and after that I update this. 
Should I make it in service layer and then use simple repository update method liek this: ?

```
public class MyService
{
  private readonly IMyRepository = _myRepo;

  MyService(IMyRepository myRepo) //it's injectable
  {
    _myRepo = myRepo;
  }

  public void ChangeActiveField(bool isActive, int id) 
  {
     var myObject = _myRepo.GetMyObject(id);
     myObject.IsActive = isActive;
    _myRepo.Update(myObject);
  }

}
```

Is it better aproach? Does it make better separation? Or it's too sophisticated and overwrite?
*Thank you for your help.
Best regards.*

Comment: With such small example IMO it just makes it...testable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general repository should encapsulate **only** the logic of accessing database (initialization of context, transactions, connections and etc.). It is very common to create a generic CRUD repository and reuse it for all your business entities.
All the business related logic should be placed in business layer(service layer).
The major benefits of this approach are:

1. Testability - you can test your business logic without relying on concrete repository implementation by injecting fake repositories(stubs).
2. Decoupling - neither your business layer nor your UI are not coupled to specific database, If tomorrow you will decide to migrate your database for example from SQL server to Redis(NoSQL database), your changes will be contained on repository layer only.
3. Maintainability - there is a clear separation of concerns for each layer: UI - interaction with user, BL - implementation of business logic, Repository - interaction with DB.

In my experience having a business layer (no matter how simple it is at the beginning - it's often grows up together with your project) is always a good idea.

By the way some developers consider repository as an unnecessary layer of abstraction in case that you use EF (in a way EF database context is a repository...).

One thing I've learned, is that the major effort is not a development phase of a project it is it's maintenance and upgrades - and here having a business layer a significant impact.

*Disclaimer: It is my subjective opinion based on my experience*

Comment: Thank's for the answer. What about when I want get Active or InActive objects? Should I implement it inside a repository? (It would only fetch necessary items but then I can't use generic repo) or get all items into memory and then filter them and return via service?

Comment: On of the methods of your generic repository could be GetCollection<T> that returns IQueriable<T>. So the actual query that is going to be generated and later executed will contain all the filters applied. The query is going to be executed only on collection enumeration (for example when you call ToList() method). So if your service gets a IQueriable from the repository applies all the filters and then calls ToList() - all the filtering is going to be performed in DB.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: 
IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> expression); ?
I've read that exposing IQueryable outside the repo layer is bad approach when you want to unit test your service layer. (and I want to to id in my app)

Comment: I don't think that exposing IQueryable outside the repository is bad approach. And it is definitely doesn't interfere with service testing. Lets say you have fake repository that works with in-memory data base and stores your objects in List. You can always AsQueriable() method